# request to https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate, nodejs, cPanel

Tags: paypal, ssl-certificate, cpanel, node-fetch, nodejs-server

I'm creating a nodejs app with paypal buttons.
The app works on local computer just fine, but I have problems with integrating it with cPanel. The application works as a server behind the passenger reverse port binding and tries to fetch data from PayPal.
I'm following paypal standard integration from `https://github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/standard-integration` which uses node-fetch to fetch data from PayPal. And got an error on trying to create a token when the user initiates payment by clicking a PayPal 'buy now' button:

```
request to https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I've tried to resolve this error by installing syswide-cas module (which should allow me to load a whole directory with SSL certificates provided by cPanel (`/ssl/certs`)) but got a similar error from npm:

```
37 silly fetch manifest syswide-cas@^5.3.0
38 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
39 silly placeDep ROOT syswide-cas@ OK for: @paypalcorp/standard-integration@1.0.0 want: ^5.3.0
40 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 70142ms
41 timing idealTree:node_modules/syswide-cas Completed in 0ms
42 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 70144ms
43 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
44 timing idealTree Completed in 70255ms
45 timing command:install Completed in 70267ms
46 verbose type system
47 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/syswide-cas failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
47 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
47 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
47 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
49 verbose Linux 4.18.0-425.19.2.lve.el7h.x86_64
50 verbose node v18.16.0
51 verbose npm  v9.5.1
52 error code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
53 error errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
54 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/syswide-cas failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

How to solve this issue either using syswide-cas module or not? I don't have access to a console on cPanel and don't want to use unsafe practices.

Comment: The usual solution is to update the root certificates on the server itself, which you may need your webhost to do for you. Failing that, you may need to use unsafe SSL just to be able to download and install something like syswide-cas and configure it with the root certificates or specific server certificates (including PayPal api endpoints') so you are able to make safe HTTPS calls.

Comment: @PrestonPHX the root certificates (I think, I'm not sure if I can recognize root certificates from any other certificates) on the server are newly generated so updating them might not help. The issue is that I guess node can't access fhem from behind the proxy? Or something similar, I'm new at this. + I'm not sure how to even enable unsafe SSL without access to a console...

Comment: You can find a good CA cert bundle here: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html -- if node doesn't have access to the system's certs, talk to your webhost about what to do about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved without `syswide-cas` module.

What was needed was ca cert bundle ( for example one form  [curl.se/docs/caextract.html](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) as Preston PHX suggested in their comment)

and SSL_CERT_FILE variable in the .env file with path to the ca cert bundle as a value.

.env:

```
SSL_CERT_FILE="./cacert.pem"
```